# Reading data from a security token in a browser

Tags: javascript, security, usb

I would like to write a **JS function** to have access from the browser to the public data stored on the **[hardware security token](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_token) inserted in an USB port**.

Specifically, in an intranet where ALL users have security tokens, I would like to have some sort of landing page, which will ask the user to enter his/her security token credentials (inserted in the USB port), and then **read the public information from that token** (I do not really need ALL of them, but I am interested mostly in the user name, certificate name(s) loaded in the token and their expiration date) and **load them in the web page (to be displayed)**.

I have little to none experience with security devices like that, but I assume this is not a very complicated issue (though "googling" did not manage to get me in the right direction of how to make it work).

Thank you.

Comment: To access USB Token from modern browsers, free Signer.Digital Browser Extension provides series of [Javascript APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885)

Answer (score 2):

In my company we created a service installed installed in client's device, this service uses **java** to access the token and it provides an **API**(in client localhost), not sure if it's the best way but it works, if you find another way to solve this issue please leave a comment.

Comment: Dajalmar, do you sign the document on the service or just read the key and serves it over the api?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WinUSB API implemented in [Chrome v54+](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/access-usb-devices-on-the-web).

You'll need to know the intrinsic structure of your USB token.